# How can I delete a dataflow job using gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am attempting to delete a Google Cloud Dataflow job using gcloud and its failing for a reason I don't understand:

```sh
# gcloud dataflow --project=XXXX jobs cancel --region=europe-west2 bhp-dp-pubsub-to-datalake
Failed to cancel job [bhp-dp-pubsub-to-datalake]: (fe9655fb12e69cb6): Could not cancel 
workflow; user does not have sufficient permissions on project: XXX, or the job does not 
exist in the project. Please ensure you have permission to access the job and the `--
region` flag, europe-west2, matches the job's region.
```

I know that I have permission to cancel jobs because I can do it from the UI.

Anyone any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Can try job id rather than job name when cancel the job? See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/cancel

Comment: Aha, thank you, that sorted it.